# Direction API return only one route when specify waypoints

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm using Direction API to display the routes between source and destination. I formed the URL like this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=11.030342,77.038737&destination=11.0254792,76.968749&mode=driving&alternatives=true

it is giving "**multiple routes**" like this

```
`{"routes" : 
[
{  }
{  }
{  }
]}`
```

but when i add the waypoints in the URL

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=11.030342,77.038737&destination=11.0254792,76.968749&mode=driving&alternatives=true&waypoints=11.037647,77.037447

it is giving "**single route**" like this

```
`{
 "routes" : 
 [{ 
 "legs" : [  {  }, {  }  ]
 }]
 }`
```

I specified the waypoint near to the starting location, still am getting single route only.

is there any mistake in my URL or it's direction API nature ??

Anyone faced this issue??

Answer (score 2):

According to this [article](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters)

> Generally, only **one** entry in the routes array is returned for directions lookups, though the Directions service **may** return several routes if you pass alternatives=true.

So there is no guarantee that will get some alternative routes if you added `alternatives=true`

Comment: if i specify "alternatives=true" without waypoints , its giving multiple routes. When i add **waypoints** , its giving only one route.. i specified the waypoints latlng near to origin location.

Comment: @thamim Yes, you are right, but looks like `Direction API` works not in that way. If you try to build the route between three points on maps.google.com, you will get only one route. So my suggestion is, that it's just not specified in the documentation.

Comment: When you add a waypoint, you split the route into two parts: route A->B and route B->C. So in this case you might have 3 alternatives for first part and 3 alternatives for second part that will result in 9 different combinations. I think Directions API just avoid such kind of multiplication of combinations and provide only one result for routes with waypoints. https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=11.030342%2C77.038737&destination=11.0254792%2C76.968749&mode=driving&waypoints=11.037647%2C77.037447&alternatives=true

Comment: Thanks xomena for your web link.. I have used as like getting response now.

Answer (score 0):

The docs may have changed from the time this question was posted. But now (in 2021) they are clear:

`waypoints`:

> ... Waypoints alter a route by directing it through the specified
> location(s)...

`alternatives`:

> ... This is only available for requests without intermediate
> waypoints.

So, yes, if you use `waypoints` you will get just one route, regardless of the `alternatives` prop's value.

[Current docs here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#optional-parameters)